# How to track queries made through xpath from my website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-scraping, xpath

Let's say I have a website and I don't want anyone else to get the data from me using xpath.

I have just made a quick experiment.

I have a websiteA.com from which I copied the xpath.

I have uploaed the xpath query code on a websiteB.com.

```
<?php

$html_string = file_get_contents('https://www.websiteA.com/' );
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$values = array();
$row = $xpath->query('//query');
foreach($row as $value) {
   print($value->nodeValue);
}

?>
```

On a websiteA I have Google Analytics installed.

The interesting part, is that when I make a query on websiteB.com (print data from websiteA),
Google Analytics doesn't show anything at all. It's like no one even visited my website.

My question is, how do you know if anyone is taking data from your site with xpath?

How do you track and identify that?

Or is this somehow identifiable on a database query level?

Comment: Your webserver logs should show that the request occurred. Bit weird that analytics didn't show _anything_ - I am not familiar with it much, but doesn't it count requests? What report were you looking at exactly? I assume it can slice and dice the data in multiple ways.

Comment: `is this somehow identifiable on a database query level`...only if calling that URL also calls your database. But the DB wouldn't know where the request originated. HTTP webserver logs might, depending on how they're configured.

Comment: I see. Yeah, it's odd that web analytics doesn't show anything at all. It counts visits from real people and bots. I doubt it can count database requests. OK, thanks for your answer.

Comment: In any case, your server A (and analytics) would only see a HTTP request, they can't know what happens next on server B (xpath). The best you can do is guess, using informations such as request frequency/pattern, IP address, user-agent, etc, but those can all be controlled/modified by the person scrapping your website A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is called *scraping* your web page. The php program you showed us downloads a page into a text string, then uses the `->xpath()` code to extract information from the string.

To prevent scraping, you must prevent the download. But that is difficult: to display the page a web browser also downloads it. And, a search engine crawler does the same.

You may need to require user authentication (username / password / optional second factor) before you allow download if you must prevent scraping.

Why didn't analytics capture the page download? Usually some Javascript in the page posts the analytics data. Browsers run the pages's Javascript, but `file_get_contents()` does not.

You know all the hoopla about how information on the web is open to all? This is why.